# Silverlight wcf and ClientCredentials

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I don't want to set the same username and password 100 times for ClientCredentials.  I want a pattern where I can set this once in code then have it automatically set.

How do people typically do this?  Do they inherit from the wcf class?  Do they use partial classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate the responsibility of creating the proxy instance to a separate class. This class can have method to create proxy, assign credentials and return the proxy instance back.This is something similar to creating factory classes for construction of an object.